# Qual o melhor método de montar o Meta-Tags para SEO?

Tags: seo, html-meta-tag

Aprendendo um pouco sobre SEO, percebi que há inúmeras meta-tags e muitas formas de mostrar ao google o titulo de um site, a descrição e tudo mais. Porém com essa pesquisa foi gerada uma dúvida.

*Qual a melhor forma de montar o Meta para SEO?*

> Há alguma que o Google lê com mais prioridade?
>
> Há alguma que o Google lê com menos prioridade?

Ou o melhor mesmo é usar *meta content* e se garantir com o simples ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na realidade você precisa apenas de 2 tags para que o Google entenda o seu conteúdo. A `description` que conterá uma descrição do conteúdo da página e a tag `title` que conterá o titulo principal da página.

Com essas duas tags o Googlebot será capaz de entender e rankear seu site, obviamente existem outras tags que vão lhe ajudar no SEO, porém para quem esta começando o importante é se focar no feijão com arroz e evitar  [over-optimization](http://searchengineland.com/too-much-seo-google%E2%80%99s-working-on-an-%E2%80%9Cover-optimization%E2%80%9D-penalty-for-that-115627)

Comment: Deu pra entender, focar no simples e no conteúdo certo? Obrigado Renato

Comment: Isso ai, conteúdo sempre foi e sempre será o melhor para SEO.